# Product of sets containing tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I work out the Cartesian product of two sets containing tuples?

$A := \{(a,b)\}$

$ B:= \{(c,d,e)\}$

Would this:
$ A \times B = \{((a,b),(c,d,e))\} $
be correct?

Comment: Yup, it will be correct.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.